# Regex to match at least one letter from a set without repetitions

Tags: regex, posix

For example if the set of letters is is {A,B,C}, I would like to match

A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC

Basically all combinations (except the empty string) taken from a set without replacement.

EDIT: I'd like to be able to do it with POSIX "grep -E".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
^(([abc])(?!.*\2))*$
```

[**Demo**](http://www.rubular.com/r/chs5VnZHd0)